# React 16 : componentDidUpdate Warning: Scheduled a cascading update

Tags: performance, reactjs, redux, react-redux, google-chrome-devtools

I profiled the performance of my application using react redux by following  [this article by Ben Schwarz](https://building.calibreapp.com/debugging-react-performance-with-react-16-and-chrome-devtools-c90698a522ad).

In the user timing section, i get these warnings (with a no entry sign):

[image]

There is two messages:

- `(Committing Changes) Warning: Lifecycle hook scheduled a cascading update`
- `Connect(MyComponent).componentDidUpdate Warning: Scheduled a cascading update`

I made some search but i found nothing special. It seems related to the `componentDidUpdate` function of the connect HOC of react-redux.

**What does these messages means ?**

Answer (score 7):

The messages mean that componentDidUpdate is getting changed props or setting the state and so the update will cascade (happen right after the last update) because it is the last lifecycle method called during an update. Basically React has determined that another update needs to happen and it isn't even finished with it's current update yet. I'm not sure if this is a problem with react-redux or your application.

Comment: ...and what happens at this point ? Will it continue with the previous update, or start with the new update, or merge both of them ? Is this case actually a problem ??

Comment: The next update just happens right after the current one, I'm actually not sure how fiber handles this so other things may happen before the next update but the update will be a part of the next render cycle.

Comment: But that does mean that the update that triggered won't be active during the current render cycle so you could potentially be trying to reference bad data and it will not be synchronized.